# implementing runnable interface in thread and use of this keyword

Tags: java

What is the purpose of implementing runnable interface in threads?
and what is the purpose of "this" keyword? With examples

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of implementing runnable interface in threads?

We can either extend `Thread` which will implicitly implement `Runnable` but then we can't `extends`   any other class, so implementing `Runnable` is better approch

> what is the purpose of "this" keyword?

`this` refers to current object on which method is executing